# Node connection timeout function?

Tags: connections, node-discovery, discovery-protocol

I am trying multiple avenues to find out why my nodes in a private blockchain are losing connectivity over the course of about 18 hours.

So this question is:

Is there a part of the discovery protocol that prevents nodes from reconnecting for a certain period of time after they lose connection?

And a follow up is if there is a part of the protocol that rotates the connections, or that has a timeout on the length of time that two nodes can stay connected?

I am looking at the Parity and geth codebases for answers, and I did search the yellowpaper for "time" and came up empty.  So it's also worth asking the question here.